# Guaranteed space to write files to?

Tags: android, android-file

In my app I want to save quite a lot of settings and configurations. 
Initially they are read from a text file in the assets folder.
They are being updated fromn the server from time to time.

I thought about two options: 
Save them in the Sqlite database via Ormlite or save them as a JSON string in a text file. 
I found out that reading them from JSON is faster than reading them from the database, so I'D prefer that option. 
But I also remember from some apps I did quite some time ago that I always ran into issues when writing files to the device, Sdcards not being available, permission stuff etc.

Is there any space / path on the Android file system that I am guaranteed to be able to use from my code and that is guaranteed to be available at any time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#InternalVsExternalStorage):

> **Internal storage:**
>
> - It's always available.
> - Files saved here are accessible by only your
>     app by default.
> - When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes
>     all your app's files from internal storage.

Unless something very unexpected happen, you can safely use Internal storage.

But as @zmarties said, use `SharedPreferences` - it's easier to use and should be enough to contain your big data.

Answer (score 0):

Save the JSON string in SharedPreferences - even easier than dealing with files yourself